# Show that this measure theory statement is closed under countable unions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We say that a set $ A \subset [0,1]$ is dyadic-($\epsilon,n$) if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist a set $B$ which is the union of dyadic interval $[p/2^n,(p+1)/2^n]$ at scale $2^{-n}$ such that $A$ and $B$ differ on a set of measure less than $\epsilon$. I want to prove the following statement: " if $A$ is a Lebesgue measurable set, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist an integer $n$ such that $A$ is dyadic-($\epsilon,n$)". I can prove this with a direct proof (regularity of measure and dyadic coverings), but I'm interested in a $\sigma$-albegra constructive proof. To conclude such proof I need to show that the claim ("for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist an integer $n$ such that $A$ is dyadic-($\epsilon,n$)") is closed under countable union. Hope now it makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: how can a statement be closed under countable unions?

Comment: In the sense that if it's true for every set of a family (countable), then it's true for the union of such sets

Comment: You never use $\epsilon$ in your definition of dyadic-($\epsilon, n$)?

Comment: Oh sorry...mistake again

Answer (score 1):

This holds for any $(B_i)\subset \mathcal{B}([0,1])$, maybe you stated the problem in a wrong way. Let $M$ be any integer, and note that
$$
A_M=\bigcup_{n=0}^{2^M-1} \left[  n/2^M,(n+1)/2^M \right] =[0,1]
$$
yields that

$$
\mu\left(\bigcup_{i}^{\infty} B_i \setminus A_{M}\right)=\mu(\emptyset)=0 < \epsilon$$
for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: I'll edit in another way, I'm sorry.